# React Table not updating value the first time

Tags: reactjs, react-table

Have an issue with React table not updating when SetState is called the first time.
In the sample code below, the InputBox in the table shows the value from toggleViewState variable declared at class level

When the form loads for the first time it correctly shows the value as **true** in the table

But when cliked on the button to toggle the state, the input box does not show the updated value on first click, it only shows the updated value on the second click with value as **false**

Code Extract

```
const [toggleViewState, setToggleViewState] = useState(true); 

const columns = [
 {
      dataIndex: 'targetRowValue',
      key: 'temp',
      width: '20%',
      render: (text, record, index) => (
        <Input size="medium" value={toggleViewState}/>        
      ),
    },
  ];

const onSwitchViewState = () => {
  setToggleViewState(!toggleViewState);
}


return (
    <div>
      {targetData.length > 0 && (
        <Table
          data={targetData}
          style={{ wordBreak: 'break-all' }}
          columns={columns}
          striped          
        />
      )}
<div className="lmn-mt-3">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>`your text`
<Button onClick={onSwitchViewState}>Toggle View</Button>
</td>
</tr></table></div></div>
```

Have tried using useMemo hook add to add dependency on the toggleViewState variable while declaring the columns definition but it did not work`

Answer (score 0):

Your question is mostly lacking data, and its hard to know whats going on inside the table. The state updates fine. However looking at the code I can take a guess. This is probably happening because React doesn't see your `Input` element as different during the dom update. Try adding a key to your input element :

```js
 render: (text, record, index) => (
        <Input size="medium" value={toggleViewState} key={`${toggleViewState}-${index}`} />        
      ),
```